# Conversion from string "" to type 'Long' is not valid. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

Im trying view all information with image from datagridview to the textboxes and picturebox. but if my Isbn have dash(-) or letters, there's a error.

My code is these

```
  Private Sub Load_Image(ByVal iIMageID As Long)
    Dim sConnString As String

    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim myMS As New IO.MemoryStream

    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader


    Try

        Call ConnectDatabase()


        Dim query As String
        query = "select ISBN, Subject, BookName, Publisher, Author, PublishingYear, Status, image from Books where ISBN= " & iIMageID
        Command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = Command.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read

                Label2.Text = reader("ISBN")
                Label3.Text = reader("Subject")
                Label1.Text = reader("BookName")
                Label4.Text = reader("Publisher")
                Label5.Text = reader("Author")
                Label6.Text = reader("PublishingYear")
                Label7.Text = reader("Status")



                arrImage = reader("image")
                For Each ar As Byte In arrImage
                    myMS.WriteByte(ar)
                Next
                '
                Me.PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
            End While
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

then in CellcontentClick event

```
 Load_Image(Me.MetroGrid1.Item(0, Me.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The LoadImage parameter is defined as a Long. Try using a string instead.

```
Private Sub Load_Image(ByVal iIMageID As String)
```

You will also have to add single quotes to the SQL call.

```
    query = "select ISBN, Subject, BookName, Publisher, Author, PublishingYear, Status, image from Books where ISBN= '" & iIMageID & "'"
```

For security, consider creating a stored procedure and calling that.